# UIImageView drag and drop on another

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uiimageview

I need to drag my one UIImageview and when I drop it on another UIImageview, it must replace in between.

[image]

As per above picture, I have many UIImageview set in a sequence. Here I required, if one drag 4-0.4 to 4-2.4 then both exchange itself.

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/ra1028/RAReorderableLayout and http://blog.karmadust.com/drag-and-drop-between-uicollectionviews/

Answer (score 0):

from touches method you can the view at the location when your touches ended. now you have both the views, one you was dragging and the one on which you have dragged your image view to. You can replace the frames of both with or without animation.

Comment: Hello @Surbhi, I'm pretty new to iOS(specially in swift). Is it possible for you to upload small demo.

Comment: @ManishJain Sure give me some time.

Comment: I can't use collectionview because my layout is random, and having fix layout having some UIImageview on layout on fix place. In advance Big Thanks for your time for creating demo.

Comment: I would suggest create view by using code, or from nib, but do not use tableview here, it will be easy to manage and drag.